# Gatsby: React conditional rendering based on window.innerWidth misbehaving

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby, server-side-rendering

Conditional rendering of components based on `window.innerWidth` seems to not work as intended just in the **production** build of Gatsby based website.

The hook I am using to check the viewport's width, with the additional check for the window global to avoid Gatsby-node production build errors, is the following:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useWindowWidth = () => {
  const windowGlobal = typeof window !== 'undefined'

  if(windowGlobal) {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)

    useEffect(() => {
      const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth)
      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
      }
    })

    return width
  }
}

export default useWindowWidth
```

Then in my actual component I do the following:

```
IndexPage.Booking = () => {
  const windowWidth = useWindowWidth()

  return (
    <div className="section__booking__wrapper">
      { windowWidth <= mediaQueries.lg && <IndexPage.Cta /> }
      <div className="section__booking-bg" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bg})` }}>
        { windowWidth > mediaQueries.lg && <IndexPage.Cta /> }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It works as it should in `development` but the **production** build fails to render:

```
<div className="section__booking-bg" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bg})` }}>
```

When resizing the window below the mediaQueries.lg (1024) it then triggers the actual normal behaviour or conditionally rendering mobile and desktop versions of the component.

To doublecheck if it was because the render triggers on just the `resize` event (which it doesn't as it works on load in `development` environment) I also simply, from within the hook `console.log()` the return value and it gets printed, in **production** correctly on load.

There are also no errors or warnings in the **production** or `development` build whatsoever.

**Edit as per @Phillip 's suggestion**

```
const useWindowWidth = () => {
  const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined'
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(isBrowser ? window.innerWidth : 0)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isBrowser) return false

    const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth)
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  })

  return width
}
```

It now works just when you resize it, once, under the mediaQueries.lg threshold and then it works flawlessly across desktop and mobile but not on load.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem to this and haven't found a solution, but a work around. Put the following at the start of your render:

```
if (typeof window === `undefined`) {
    return(<></>);
}
```

What I think is happening is that Gatsby is building the page with a style based off the window width (which will be 0 / undefined). Then it's not updating the style in the DOM once the page loads as it thinks it has already performed that action. I think this is a small bug in Gatsby maybe?

Either way, the above renders your component blank during the build, forcing it to fully respect all logic when the page loads. Hopefully that provides a solution albeit not a satisfying/complete explanation :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try that out although it leaves me with a bitter aftertaste ahah

Comment: I was having the same problem (I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805587/gatsby-server-side-rendering-of-page-with-client-only-routes-based-on-window-lo) and this fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: it work's partly for me html rendered as it should be but css is not loaded properly:(

Comment: Great answer and explanation but IMO the solution could be improved. You don't need to hide the whole component during SSR, it's enough to hide just the bit that is affected by `window`. That way you still get the most out of Gatsby. Something like this should work in the OP's case: `{ typeof window === "undefined" ? <></> : windowWidth <= mediaQueries.lg && <IndexPage.Cta /> }` (not tested but I'm sure this or something very similar would work).

Comment: Agreed @Avius, there are more specific ways of solving this issue that produce better results. I simplified my answer as I think it's more helpful to everyone as an explanation of the issue and a fix, rather than fixing just the OP's code :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it is too late to answer but calling handleResize before adding the event listener should work. Here is a code I used for same purpose:

```
  useEffect(() => {
  setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  });
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", () => {});
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions** ([from React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html))

React Hooks *must* run in the exact same order on *every* render. Move your condition into the `useEffect` callback:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return;

  const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
  };
});
```

Comment: I knew there was something fishy about calling a hook like that within a condition, still I didn't pay attention to that. Will try and let you know, thanks for your help!

Comment: The same is happening after I amended the code asa per my edit in my answer: now, in `development` it just works when you resize the window below the threshold then both desktop and mobile work as intended.

Comment: Any clues why would that be?