# Gatsby server-side rendering of page with client-only routes, based on window location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering, reach-router

I am working on a Gatsby project (a language learning blog) and am having trouble with an issue that only happens in production builds due to server-side rendering.

I programmatically generate a page for each blog post with the following scheme:
`/posts/{post-name}`. Each post can also have a number of subpaths that map to open tabs in the UI. For example, `/posts/important-spanish-verbs/lesson` would open the lesson tab. Each page has a `matchPath` property of `/posts/{post-name}/*`, and these are handled as client-only routes, implemented with `reach-router`.

With `gatsby develop`, the app works exactly as intended. When I visit `/posts/some-post/podcast`, it successfully opens to the podcast tab and I can see the active tab being set correctly.

The problem is that with `gatsby build && gatsby serve`, when I fresh-load a URL that directly navigates to a specific tab inside of the post (either manually visiting the whole URL or refreshing), the active tab is *not* set correctly in the UI.

The following snippet (highly simplified and condensed to demonstrate the issue) roughly outlines the problem:

```js
function TabbedLayout({ children, basePath }) {
  return (
    <LocationProvider>
      {({ location }) => {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <ul>
              React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
                const isActive = child.props.path === location.pathname
                console.log(`tab ${child.props.path} active? ${isActive}`)
                return <li className={isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'}>{/* construct a link based on child props */}</li>
              })
            </ul>
            <Router basepath={basePath}>
              {children}
            </Router>
          </Fragment>
        )
      }}
    </LocationProvider>
}
```

What happens when I run my code which uses the method demonstrated above in a *production build* (with SSR) is that when I visit for example `posts/example-post/lesson`:

- The *content* is rendered correctly via Reach router (i.e. the *content* of the lesson tab is open)
- The lesson tab has class `inactive` (an error)
- In the console, I see `tab /posts/example-post/lesson active? true` printed, even though the CSS class didn't get updated!

I've tried everything I can think of to try to update the UI. As soon as I click a different tab and the window location changes *without a refresh*, everything updates fine and the active tab UI works as expected, but I just cannot seem to get it to re-render based on the `isActive` variable.

Does anyone know a way to fix or work around this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to find a workaround for the issue, although it's a bit frustrating to not understand in detail why the problem is actually happening.

If I wrap the tab `<li>`s (which don't correctly show as active/inactive on first load with SSR) in a condition to check that we're in the browser, it works:

```js
return typeof window !== 'undefined' && (
  <li className={isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'}>
    {/* construct a link based on child props */}
  </li>
)
```