# gatsby + react hook masonry breaks on build because there is no window

Tags: reactjs, window, react-hooks, gatsby

I have a react hook set up to handle masonry on certain pages of my gatsby site. The problem is it references the window object, which does not exist on the server side `gatsby build`. [I've read that the solution is to wrap useEffect with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608523/gatsby-react-conditional-rendering-based-on-window-innerwidth-misbehaving):

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
}
```

however I just can't seem to wrap the right part of my masonry file. I've also read that using the above hack makes the server side rendering sort of pointless, not sure.

Could someone tell me where that if statement should go in my masonry file below? It's not a plugin, it's a hook in my utils folder. [Using code from this tut](https://janosh.io/blog/react-hooks-masonry). I've tried the if statement inside the useEffects, around the useEffects, around the whole eventListener, but no dice. Thank you!!

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

const useEventListener = (eventName, handler, element = window) => {
  const savedHandler = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    savedHandler.current = handler
  }, [handler])

  useEffect(() => {
    const isSupported = element && element.addEventListener
    if (!isSupported) return

    const eventListener = event => savedHandler.current(event)
    element.addEventListener(eventName, eventListener)

    return () => {
      element.removeEventListener(eventName, eventListener)
    }
  }, [eventName, element])
}

const fillCols = (children, cols) => {
  children.forEach((child, i) => cols[i % cols.length].push(child))
}

export default function Masonry({ children, gap, minWidth = 500, ...rest }) {
  const ref = useRef()
  const [numCols, setNumCols] = useState(3)
  const cols = [...Array(numCols)].map(() => [])
  fillCols(children, cols)

  const resizeHandler = () =>
    setNumCols(Math.ceil(ref.current.offsetWidth / minWidth))
  useEffect(resizeHandler, [])
  useEventListener(`resize`, resizeHandler)

  const MasonryDiv = styled.div`
    margin: 1rem auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
  `
  const Col = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
  `

  return (
    <MasonryDiv ref={ref} gap={gap} {...rest}>
      {[...Array(numCols)].map((_, index) => (
        <Col key={index} gap={gap}>
          {cols[index]}
        </Col>
      ))}
    </MasonryDiv>
  )
}
```

Comment: You might want to use something like [masonic](https://github.com/jaredLunde/masonic) or [react-masonry-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-component) instead of trying to re-implement Masonry in React.

Comment: I wanted a specific type of masonry that's columned but the divs read chronologically left to right, otherwise would have totally used that

Comment: Ah, interesting!

Answer (score 2):

In your `gatsby-node.js` add the following snippet:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /masonry/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

*Note: use `/masonry/` library path from your `node_modules`.*

From Gatsby documentation about [debugging HTML builds](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/#fixing-third-party-modules):

> Errors while building static HTML files generally happen for one of
>   the following reasons:
>
> Some of your code references “browser globals” like window or
>   document. If this is your problem you should see an error above like
>   “`window` is not defined”. To fix this, find the offending code and
>   either a) check before calling the code if window is defined so the
>   code doesn’t run while Gatsby is building (see code sample below) or
>   b) if the code is in the render function of a React.js component, move
>   that code into a `componentDidMount` lifecycle or into a `useEffect` hook,
>   which ensures the code doesn’t run unless it’s in the browser.

Alternatively, you can wrap your import your Masonry hook usage inside this statement:

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
  const module = require("module")
}
```

*Note the `!==` comparison, not the `===` like the one you've provided.*

Comment: the masonry hook isn't a node library, it's a js file in my utils/ folder, when I populate test: with utils/masonry.js it doesn't work? this is the masonry system I'm using https://janosh.io/blog/react-hooks-masonry

Comment: Try to wrap your Masonry hook usage inside the comparison I've added (`typeof window !== 'undefined'`).

Comment: @FerranBuireu, Could you review and answer to my question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66958067/cant-use-react-useeffect-and-also-build-failed-using-gatsby