# Can't use React useEffect and also build failed using Gatsby

Tags: react-hooks, gatsby, server-side-rendering, headless, vercel

I am building a headless eCommerce website using [Nacelle](https://nacelle.com/), Gatsby, and Shopify plus.

My problem is that I integrated [Okendo](https://www.okendo.io/) API to fetch product reviews and can't build the project.

Actually, as you know, headless eCommerce is a new technology to us, but it is mostly close to Gatsby and SSR.

I tried to go 2 ways, one is to include the script to `head` using [gatsby-react-helmet](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/), and another one is to call window api inside `useEffect` or `useLayoutEffect`.

**1. Including the script to head tag using gatsby-plugin-react-helmet.**

ProductReview.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

import transformProductId from '../../utils/transformProductId';
import { PRODUCT_REVIEW_METAFIELD_KEY, OKENDO_SUBSCRIBER_ID } from '../../constants';

const ProductReview = ({
  product
}) => {
  const OkendoSettings = {
    filtersEnabled: true,
    omitMicrodata: true,
    subscriberId: OKENDO_SUBSCRIBER_ID,
    widgetTemplateId: "default"
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="../plugins/okendo/index.js" />
        <script type="application/json" id="oke-reviews-settings">
          {JSON.stringify(OkendoSettings)}
        </script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="../plugins/okendo/initAPI.js" />
      </Helmet>
      <div
        data-oke-reviews-widget
        data-oke-reviews-product-id={transformProductId(product.id)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default React.memo(ProductReview);
```

/plugin/okendo/index.js

```
(function () {
  function asyncLoad() {
      var urls = ['https:\/\/d3hw6dc1ow8pp2.cloudfront.net\/reviewsWidget.min.js?shop=example.myshopify.com'];
      for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
          var s = document.createElement('script');
          s.type = 'text/javascript';
          s.async = true;
          s.src = urls[i];
          var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
      }
  }
  if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent('onload', asyncLoad);
  } else {
      window.addEventListener('load', asyncLoad, false);
  }
})();
```

/plugin/okendo/initAPI.js

```
window.okeReviewsWidgetOnInit = function (okeInitApi) {};
```

If I include the Okendo scripts to head tag, it works all fine.
But when I try to build on [vercel](https://vercel.com/), it says "error Building static HTML failed for path /products/example-product-slug".

[image]

**2. Calling window.init api inside useEffect.**

ProductReview.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

import transformProductId from '../../utils/transformProductId';
import { PRODUCT_REVIEW_METAFIELD_KEY, OKENDO_SUBSCRIBER_ID } from '../../constants';

const ProductReview = ({
  product
}) => {
  const OkendoSettings = {
    filtersEnabled: true,
    omitMicrodata: true,
    subscriberId: OKENDO_SUBSCRIBER_ID,
    widgetTemplateId: "default"
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== `undefined` && window.okendoInitApi) {
      const reviewsWidget = window.document.querySelector('#oke-reviews-widget');
      window.okendoInitApi.initReviewsWidget(reviewsWidget);
    }
  }, [product.id]);

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="../plugins/okendo/index.js" />
        <script type="application/json" id="oke-reviews-settings">
          {JSON.stringify(OkendoSettings)}
        </script>
        {/* <script type="application/javascript" src="../plugins/okendo/initAPI.js" /> */}
      </Helmet>
      <div
        id="oke-reviews-widget"
        data-oke-reviews-widget
        data-oke-reviews-product-id={transformProductId(product.id)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default React.memo(ProductReview);
```

While I am using `useEffect` to initialize Okendo api, it works only when the page refresh, not work if I open a page.

And if I try to build it, it says "error "window" is not available during server side rendering.".

[image]

I know `useEffect` doesn’t run unless it’s in the browser, but still I don't get what the solution is.

Hope to hear a good news.

Thank you.

UPDATE: The product id is generated from Shopify product graphql data named `handle`.

gatsby-node.js

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions: { createPage } }) => {
  // Fetch all products
  const products = await graphql(`
    {
      allNacelleProduct (filter: { availableForSale: {eq: true} }) {
        edges {
          node {
            handle
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);
  products.data.allNacelleProduct.edges.forEach((product) =>
    createPage({
      // Build a Product Detail Page (PDP) for each product
      path: `/products/${product.node.handle}`,
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/product-detail.js'),
      context: {
        handle: product.node.handle
      }
    })
  );
  ...
```

Comment: Is `/products/example-product-slug` a valid ID? In the second example, where are the products `useState`?

Comment: @FerranBuireu, Thank you for the comment. The id generates dynamically from graphql data. Please check my update.

Comment: Thanks. In your code, `window` it's not a dependency of the useEffect. Have you pasted the correct snippet?

Comment: @FerranBuireu, Actually, the embedded Okendo snippet code is provided from Okendo customer support. I am sure this is not for React side, it is just for PHP, jquery, or other multi-page applications, right? And I realized that `plugin/okendo/index.js` is not necessary, because the Okendo works even without the code.

Comment: @FerranBuireu So it seems it is not possible without npm module like [@okendo/okendo-widgets-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okendo/okendo-widgets-vue). What is your thought?

Comment: And I was able to use `dangerousHTML` to markdown the Okendo metafield from Shopify. I was able to apply css styles, but was not able to be dynamic, js not worked.

Comment: https://github.com/okendo/okendo-reactjs-example/tree/fa5002d97f5b78adb21ff16570c6294692e460b4 What about this?

Comment: @FerranBuireu Yes, I think what I did is similar to it. Do you think it is different with my code? https://github.com/okendo/okendo-reactjs-example/blob/fa5002d97f5b78adb21ff16570c6294692e460b4/src/App.js#L29

Comment: Actually, I am not sure how the repo works, because subscriber id for Okendo is required. But the codebase doesn't have.

Comment: Have you tried removing the memoized hook?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try creating a sandbox for testing

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time.