# How to import static js files using helmet or ssr api and how to avoid Uncaught SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, gatsby, server-side-rendering, static-assert

I am trying to import static js files using [helmet](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/) or using [Gatsby SSR API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/).

But using both of them, I always get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`.

Maybe I am getting the error because the path is not correct.

**Try 1:**

src/component/ProductDetail/ProductDetail.js

```
const ProductDetail = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <script type="application/javascript" src={"./plugins/zaius/index.js"} />
      </Helmet>
      <div css={styles.layout}>
      ...
```

Note: zaius plugin js file, the path is `static/plugins/zaius/index.js`

**Try 2:**

gatsby-ssr.js

```
export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    <script
      type="application/javascript"
      href="./plugins/zaius/index.js"
    />
  ])
}
```

My Gatsby project architecture is normal, nothing special.

```
|-- /src
    |-- /pages
    |-- /templates
    |-- html.js
|-- /static
    |-- /plugins
        |-- /zaius
            |-- index.js
|-- gatsby-config.js
|-- gatsby-node.js
|-- gatsby-ssr.js
|-- gatsby-browser.js
```

If I compile using `npm run dev`, then the structure will be:

```
|-- /plugins
    |-- /zaius
        |-- index.js
|-- index.html
```

I think the reason why I am getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` is because the zaius plugin index.js file path is wrong.

Because I tried to clean `.cache` using `gatsby clean`, and I get the error only when I import the js file.

And please refer to my previous question. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66958067/cant-use-react-useeffect-and-also-build-failed-using-gatsby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that from your `ProductDetail` the `src` should be:

```
  <Helmet>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../../plugins/zaius/index.js" />      
  </Helmet>
```

In your `gatsby-ssr.js`, this should also work:

```
export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    <script src="./plugins/zaius/index.js" />
  ])
}
```

Note that in this second try, I've changed `link` to `script` tag, since it's what you are importing (not a stylesheet).

I've tested both mocking the plugin and the structure and they are not breaking the compilation.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I was meaning `<script>`. And it worked! Thanks.